# Requesting multiple scopes in Spring Security Oauth2 version 2.0.7.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We have an application which is using `spring-security-oauth2:1.0`. I was trying to change it to a newer version, `spring-security-oauth2:2.0.7.RELEASE`. If I don't specify the `scope` or If I specify I single scope, the application works fine. I have a problem while requesting multiple scopes like `read,write`, which used to work in previous version.

The client I am requesting has all `read,write and trust` permissions.

When I was using `spring-security-oauth2:1.0`, to get a token I used to do a get call like

> http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=ws&client_secret=secret&scope=read,write&username=user@abc.com&password=temp123

If you see the scope parameter `scope=read,write`, by requesting this way I used to get a token with scope `read and write`.

If I try to do the same thing with Oauth2 version `2.0.7.RELEASE`(with a `POST` request though), I get `Invalid Scope` exception because the `tokenRequest`is taking `read,write` as a single scope. The client I am requesting has `read,write and trust` permissions but `read,write` is not one of them.

If I try it with `scope=write` or `scope=read`, It works fine because `read` or `write` are part of the client's scope.

If I want to request for multiple scopes in `OAuth2 2.0.7.RELEASE`, how do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the correct way to do this. Instead of a comma separated scopes, you have to use `+` to separate scopes.

Ex: `read+write` , `write+trust`

So the following `POST` request worked fine.

> http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=ws&client_secret=secret&scope=**read+write**&username=user@abc.com&password=temp123

I hope it will help others :)

Comment: how should i write if i have scopes read,write,trust for a client?please reply

Comment: its not working for me..Does i want to write scope in database also like this??

Comment: yes, In database you should have allowed scopes for that client.

Comment: Does i want to write the scope as read+write+trust in database??

Comment: no, in database you should have **read,write,trust** and while requesting you should have - **scope=read+write+trust**